# Can commits be automatically collected into a batch?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Is there a way to automatically put multiple updates into batches? For example, transform this program:

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE DEPT SET MGRNO=? WHERE DEPTNO=?");            
prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum1);                          
prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum1);
prepStmt.executeUpdate();                                    

prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum2);                        
prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum2);
prepStmt.executeUpdate();

con.commit();
```

into this program:

```
connection con.setAutoCommit(false);                  
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(    
  "UPDATE DEPT SET MGRNO=? WHERE DEPTNO=?");            
prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum1);                          
prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum1);
prepStmt.addBatch();                                    

prepStmt.setString(1,mgrnum2);                        
prepStmt.setString(2,deptnum2);
prepStmt.addBatch();
int [] numUpdates=prepStmt.executeBatch();              
for (int i=0; i < numUpdates.length; i++) {             
  if (numUpdates[i] == -2)
    System.out.println("Execution " + i + 
      ": unknown number of rows updated");
  else
    System.out.println("Execution " + i + 
      "successful: " numUpdates[i] + " rows updated");
}
con.commit();
```

Could this transformation be done by a compiler automatically? What work has been done on this?

Thanks,
a database noob.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler could do this transformation but I know no compiler that does.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you could use (or code yourself) something like Spring's JDBCTemplate to give you some templated behaviour (such as commit at the end of some batches), but as @Peter G. states it's not the compiler that would do automatically do this, it's your (or a third party) code.

AOP is another option here if you're really looking to implement this.